# Beamer: sub-itemize visibility linked to previous item

Tags: beamer, itemize, overlays

Suppose I have a list where I want the item just before a sub-list to disappear somewhere during the uncovering of the sub-list. See example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item item 1.
        \item <2-> item 2
        \item <3->item 3
        \item <4-6> item 4
        \begin{itemize}
            \item <5-> item 5
            \item <6-> item 6
            \item <7-> item 7
        \end{itemize}
        \item <9-> item 9
        \item <10-> item 10     
    \end{itemize}
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

This particular example will have the sub-list's visibility linked to the item before it (item 4), but I'd like to control this separately (in this case, to match the visibility of its children). Do I need some tricks like wrapping it in a `\onslide` or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can separate the sublist from item 4 by wrapping item 4 inside `\uncover{}`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}
    \begin{itemize}[<+->]
        \item item 1.
        \item item 2
        \item item 3
        \uncover<4-6>{\item item 4}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item item 5
            \item item 6
            \item item 7
        \end{itemize}
        \item item 9
        \item item 10     
    \end{itemize}
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Or a more dynamic one, albeit not the prettiest one codewise. The `(2)` specifies, that item 4 should only be visible for the two first sub items.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}
    \begin{itemize}[<+->]
        \item item 1.
        \item item 2
        \item item 3
        \item<.(1)-+(2)> item 4
        \item[]<.-> \begin{itemize}
            \item item 5
            \item item 6
            \item item 7
        \end{itemize}
        \item item 9
        \item item 10     
    \end{itemize}
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```